# display:none not working with type="button"

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have some buttons on my ASP.NET form that need to be hidden if the user does not have sufficient permissions.  In the code behind I check permissions and add "display:none;" to the style if necessary.  This approach works with input elements that have `type="submit"` but not if `type="button"`.   Do I invisible-ize those buttons differently?

This is the HTML that results (taken from source in IE10)

```
<input type="submit" id="SaveBtn" name="SaveBtn" style="width: auto;display:none;"   title="Guest users cannot save changes" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" id="DeleteBtn" name="DeleteBtn" style="width: auto;display:none; " title="Only administrators may delete WADs" value="Delete"  />
<input type="button" id="EmailManagersBtn" style="width: auto;display:none;" title="Guest users cannot email managers" value="Email Managers" onclick="SendWADManagerEmail()" />
```

Comment: I just run the code and all the buttons are hidden.

Comment: I'm in IE10.  Maybe that makes the diff?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8LR4e/ - check this, please, in your browser

Comment: Works fine in IE10 (tested on browserstack.com)

Comment: OK - i pasted just the code above into an empty page and all buttons disappeared.  I'm going to add back elements piece by piece to see what makes it reappear.

Comment: Make sure you've closed all `'` and `"`'s, it could be messing with the code.

Comment: Doh!  I found some js that was making the button visible again.  It was just coincidence that the others were submit and this was "button".

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if a user does not have permission to view these buttons, these should not be rendered at all. CSS can be modified using tools like dev tool bar in IE and firebug in firefox.

Other than that same css (adding display:none) should hide both  and

Comment: This is true. If the user does not have permissions then use the Visible property of the Button control to prevent them from even getting rendered on the client. As it stands now, a user can simply use the JavaScript debug tools and programmatically click those buttons even if they don't have permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - there was javascript running on page load that was making the button visible again.  Thanks for the help, everyone.